# Displaying Express Query String Results In A View

Tags: express

Hello I am new to Express/MongoDB/Node. I am trying to capture and display the results of a query string that has two inputs onto a view.

Here is the form to get the query from a searchbar partial:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/searchresult" method="GET">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search Dish">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location" placeholder="zipcode">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"></button>
```

Here is the route to find the results:

```
//SEARCH Route - item query results
router.get("/searchresult", function(req,res){
    //Get search results
    Item.find({name:req.query.name, location:req.query.location}, function(err, allItems)
    {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("searchresult",{allItems});
        }    
    });
});
```

How can I display the results in a view?

```
        <div class="container">
             <h1>Search Results</h1>
        </div>
        //Need Help Here
```

Comment: First, be sure you are retrieving the data that you want (check if 'allItems' is ok).You can loop along your 'allItems' variable, but it will depends on what template engine you are using. If it's jade you can use 'each in' function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the query parameters (like `?search=foo`) you would do it like so:

```
        ...

        res.render('searchresult', {allItems: allItems, location: req.query.location});

        ...
```

You can then access `allItems` and `location` in your view, the code depends on what view engine you'e chosen.

EDIT: It's unclear if you want the databse query results, or the query string (from a get request) in your views. The answer above shows both.